# Generalized notion of perpendicularity, (not orthogonal)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, affine-geometry

In 3 dimensions, we might call 2 planes perpendicular iff their normals are orthogonal.

But this does not coincide with the definition of orthogonal subspaces - the dot product of any pair of vectors is $0$.

Is there a notion of perpendicularity any text introduces, generalising in $\mathbb R^n$ the perpendicular planes in $\mathbb R^3$?

For example - I was thinking if we had two subspaces be "perpendicular" iff they are not parallel and are the sides of some $n$-cube.

Comment: No, take V, W our subspaces. Then we require $\{v.w : v\in V, w\in W\} = \{0\}$ for them to be orthogonal subspaces.

Comment: Each plane contains the intersecting lines between them. There are lots of lines non-orthogonal to that in each. In particular, consider the xy and yz planes. (t, t, 0) is in the xy plane, but not orthogonal to the y-axis in the yz plane.

Comment: I see no difference - we can center the origin at any point where the 2 planes intersect, and it becomes a problem of linear subspaces.

Comment: you are right, it doesn't hold in general. Two orthogonal planes can share some affine subspace (an intersection line), the planes are not orthogonal in the sense of vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric algebra analyses this scenario.  In the geometric algebra, two subspaces are orthogonal means there is a vector in one that is in the orthogonal complement of the other.  This can be determined using the contraction operator, which generalizes the dot product, which is very nice.

So $V\perp W$ iff $V \rfloor W = 0$.

Comment: Interesting, thank you, any resources you'd recommend to look further into this?

Comment: The book "Linear and Geometric Algebra" by Alan MacDonald is fantastic.

Comment: I suppose one thing that differs from the n-cube idea is that any space is orthogonal to a proper subspace. Say $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ (even if embedded the natural way in higher dimensions)

Comment: @Shuri2060 Some sides of a cube are parallel, so let’s only consider three sides of a cube meeting in a corner.  Any of these sides yields a left contraction of 0 with any other.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want when stated geometrically is that affine subspaces $V$ and $W$ are "perpendicular" in your new sense if when you project both spaces onto the orthogonal complement of their intersection the resulting affine subspaces, which will meet at just one point, are orthogonal.

That's equivalent to choosing the origin as that point, then an orthogonal basis for the intersection and then extending it to an orthogonal basis of the sum by choosing new basis vectors from $V$ and $W$. That basis will define the $n$ cube you have imagined.

It don't know whether this configuration has a special name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a quite natural generalisation of the very first phrase in your question to the case of arbitrary dimension $n$, that is: we might call 2 *hyperplanes* (subspace of dimension $n-1$) perpendicular iff their normals are orthogonal.